# Text on image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
  </div>
</div>

.slider {
    width: 500px;
  margin:  auto;
}

img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}


   .projectnaam{
text-align:left;
font: 30px/30px 'grotesque_mtextracondensed', 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding:0 0 0 20px;
background-color:red;

  }

.klantnaam {
text-align:left;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: italic;
padding:0 0 0 20px;
background-color:red;

  }


$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/69/

Hello everyone,

Basically i have this image slider, under each slider i have some text. 
My problem is that when i try to position the text on the image (instead under the image) The background doesn't come with it. I tried positioning the text on the image with a negative margin-top.

This was the result of my try: [image]

Even tho there is a background on the text, it doesn't show.

So long story short I want the text to be on the image instead of under the image. (with the red background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `position` of text by `absolute` and change the `top/bottom` of them.

**[Example DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/70/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this and after adding your style:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    <span>
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
           <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
    </span>
  </div>

div {
    position: relative;
}

span { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    zindex: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 500px;
  margin:  auto;
}

img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}


   .projectnaam{
text-align:left;
font: 30px/30px 'grotesque_mtextracondensed', 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding:0 0 0 20px;
background-color:red;

  }

.klantnaam {
text-align:left;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: italic;
padding:0 0 0 20px;
background-color:red;

  }
  .main{position:relative}
  .content{position:absolute;bottom:15px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
          <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
                 <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
           <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
               <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
           <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
             <div class="content">          
           <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
                <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please check below link. hope that is what you want.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/73/]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `margin-top` ok for you, you can try to add `position:relative`.

```
 .projectnaam,.klantnaam
  {
    position:relative;
  }

  .projectnaam
  {
    margin-top: -80px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/75/

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 200px;">
<img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <p class="projectnaam">Project</p>
    <p class="klantnaam">Klantnaam</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
.projectnaam {
    text-align:left;
    font: 30px/30px 'grotesque_mtextracondensed', 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/76/)